# Google Recaptcha2 Laravel blade to html injection error

Tags: html, laravel, captcha

When I inject a laravel blade modal to an html page and I loaded the recaptcha 2 in the html page.

```
var widgetId;

    var onloadCallback = function() {
    console.log("footer captcha");

    if(typeof grecaptcha != "undefined" && widgetId == null ){
        widgetId = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'theme': 'light',
            'sitekey' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        });
    }
    if(typeof childCaptchaCallback != "undefined"){
        childCaptchaCallback();
    }
};
```

And loaded recaptcha script.Html has a form and JQvalidation . After validation of html then open that popup modal(laravel blade) and validate that(it works - jQuery validation) in modal. Close that modal and in that html page the jQuery validation fails on the next submit click.

I think when I load api.js script of recaptcha. (Grecaptcha is the object of the captcha to get and reset the captcha). But if I open a laravel blade and try to validate the grecaptcha, it is the object of that laravel page containing captcha. After closing that pop-up, the grecaptcha is to be the object of html page. But when the grecaptcha.getResponse()function is called it shows error "Invalid recaptcha client id of undefined".

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Posted. Please help

Comment: Hope this [reference](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api) will help you!